# Display Zsh shell select menu starting from zero

Tags: zsh

I have some shell functions (using Zsh) that use the `select` command to display a menu.  In one case it makes sense (based on the contents of the menu) for the first option to be numbered with `0` instead of `1`.  Is this possible?

Googling turns up very little.  Even looking for man pages gives me [results](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) for a [C system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)).

Here's a example of `select` ripped out of a random snippet (that may or may not have bugs but should illustrate the purpose nicely):

```
...
select branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
  echo -n $branch | xargs git checkout
  break
done
...
```

which would give a menu like

```
1) features/blah-blah-blah-git-branch
2) bugs/blah-blah-blah-some-bug
3) docs/updated-readme-finally
4) features/crazy-feature-request
```

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `zstyle ':completion*:default' menu 'select=0'`

Comment: @DavidMaze I just added one.

Comment: @gregory, I'm not asking about shell completion, although Googling _did_ tend to turn up results about zsh completion as well.